# Proving existence of a function with no analytic extension beyond any boundary point of a given region

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-continuation

The following is an old qualifying exam question in Complex Analysis.

> Let $G$ be the open strip $\{z \in \Bbb C | 1 < \Im(z) < 2\}$.  Prove that there exists a function $f$ that is analytic on $G$ which does not extend analytically beyond any boundary point of $G$

I would need to show that for any $z \in \partial G$ and any $\epsilon > 0$, there is no function $g$ analytic on $B(z;\epsilon)$ such that $g(z) = f(z)$ on $G \cap B(z,\epsilon)$.  My first thought is to turn this into a problem on the unit disk by applying the necessary transformation (I believe it's $\phi(z) = \frac{1 - ie^{\pi z}}{1 + ie^{\pi z}}$).  But I don't know of any functions on the unit disk which cannot be analytically extended on any boundary point of the disk; at least, I wouldn't know how to prove the existence of one.  Any hints?

Comment: $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{2^n}$ cannot be extended analytically beyond the unit disk. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lacunary_function

Comment: @DarkMalthorp, thank you, I wasn't aware of that one.  In my searching, I saw another function which couldn't be analytically extended beyond the unit disk.  My concern is that these are not functions that we have seen, so I don't think that his goal here is for us to whip out a previously known function.  How could I prove the mere existence of such a function?

Comment: The example I gave is pretty straightforward to show, because $f(x) = x + f(x^2)$, and $f(x)$ clearly blows up around $1$, so this identity can be used to show it has singularities on a dense subset of the boundary of the unit disk.

Comment: I doubt you'll be able to define such a function except in terms of series, because all the "known" functions have discrete sets of singularities (i.e. no limit points)

Comment: @DarkMalthorp, fair enough.  Thanks!